# no vale nada el parametro de n1 dentro de la funcion, con input de por medio

Tags: python, funciones, bucle-for, bucles

```
def tabla(n1):
    n1 = int(input("dime un numero"))

    print(f"la tabla de multiplicar del {n1}")

    for contador in range(1,11):
        operacion = n1*contador
        print(f"{n1} X {contador} = {operacion}")

    print("\n")

tabla(1)
```

porque se me ejecuta el programa si a la funcion le pongo 1 y no n1 como parametro?

Comment: Lo que va abajo son sólo las respuestas a tu pregunta. Si necesitas añadir info, usa le enlace `editar` que está justo bajo tu pregunta. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Hola Álvaro, no estoy muy seguro de la respuesta que te voy a dar, pero no sé si es porque en este caso, Python va ejecutando el código de manera secuencial, es decir, línea por línea, por lo que, lo primero que evalúa la función es la petición de datos y por consiguiente efectua todas las operaciones pertinentes, y no tiene en cuenta el 1 que le has pasado como parámetro. Además, no sé si influye, que ese `1` que le querías pasar se debe pasar de la forma `print(tabla(1))` pero si añades eso te devuelve el tipo `None`

Comment: No es claro a qué te refieres con lo que pusiste en "la respuesta". Sobre tu pregunta, no es claro a qué te refieres. Qué quieres decir con que le pones 1 a la función? Por favor, EDITA tu pregunta y explícanos qué intentaste poner en 1 y en n1

Comment: Tal como implementas la función, con el valor de `n1` pedido al usuario **dentro de la misma**, el parámetro directamente sobra: `def tabla(): ....` y llamar con `tabla()`. El argumento no sirve para nada tal como está, lo mismo es que le pases `1` como `None` como `"Hola"`, con tal que le pases algo...

Comment: eso  es, muchas gracias esque no entendia el porque, pero claro si yo le pido algo al usuario, me sobra que yo asigne un valor, muchas gracias,

Answer (score 0):

Esto sucede porque el parámetro que le pasas a la función es en sí, `n1` o sea, un valor. Un valor que luego lo colocas en al usar la función `tabla(1)` eso quiere decir que le estás dando una posición valida para `n1`, o sea, para poder ejecutarse, en cambio si está vacío te pide un parámetro pero al menos se lo pasas. Lo mejor sería, no pasarle ese `input` dentro, sino fuera de él. Preguntar primero, o colocar el `input` fuera de la función y luego printear la tabla con ese parámetro dentro. ejemplo:

```
def tabla(n1):

    print(f"la tabla de multiplicar del {n1}")

    for contador in range(1,11):
        operacion = n1*contador
        print(f"{n1} X {contador} = {operacion}")

    print("\n")

n1 = int(input("dime un numero"))

tabla(n1)
```

Así al mismo tiempo el número que colocas, es el mismo que utilizarás al declarar la función.

o sea, lo que quiero decir es que con colocar el 1, no le das la oportunidad de pasar sino que simplemente le pasas directamente un parámetro para ejecutar, pero no para usar el parámetro que quieres utilizar que es el `n1`, pero de la forma en que te lo coloco puedes hacer lo que estás buscando.

Comment: muchisimas gracias por la explicacion, soy muy novato y no lo entendia, muchas gracias